# PostgreSQL: stop evaluation of MAX() after reaching possible maximum

Tags: sql, postgresql

Running a query to find the `MAX()` value of an expression, I know in advance the highest possible value for the result of the `MAX()` function. As there are a lot of records, I would like the evaluation to just stop if that maximum value is encountered.

Example code:

```sql
SELECT MAX(value) FROM data;
```

would have to scan all `value` columns of `data`. But if I know that the highest possible value is `2` and there are millions of records, it could stop looking at all these records if one of the first rows encountered already contains `2` as there's no way any subsequent value is going to be higher than this.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to express this, short of using a Pl/SQL function with a cursor which is something I'd really like to avoid. Any ideas how to express this with a regular `SELECT` statement? Maybe using `WITH RECURSIVE`?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(value) FROM data LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: Sorry, I think it's not possible, because all rows need to be scanned (not if you have and index) before the database knows that `2` is the MAX value.

Comment: @Luuk since I know the highest possible value, I'd be able to encode it in the query. Right now the only construct I have found that explicitly supports terminating an evaluation is `WITH RECURSIVE` evaluation but maybe there's a functional way to express reaching the boundary condition, too.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(value) FROM data WHERE not exists(SELECT 2 FROM data WHERE value=2)`   (I do hope you have an index on `value`)

Comment: An index on `value` will make that fast. It will result in an `Index Only Scan Backward` which is pretty much the same amount of work regardless of the size of the table.

Comment: I should never (try to) answer these kind of question again , see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=73f80ae7043ac34405b58cf786bb2e59   It seems to be the most expensive way...

Comment: So far there's no index on `value` as there are many distinct values in it and an index would grow very large. Given the large range of possible values, I'm not sure that the query planner would always take it into consideration. The `NOT EXISTS()` construct is worth a try. Although I worry it might have to scan the table twice if `value=2` doesn't exist. Thanks for giving it a shot, though, much appreciated! I was worried I was overlooking something very straightforward due to limited familiarity with SQL.

Comment: Indexes can handle many distinct values without problems. Proof: every primary key is backed by an index and - by definition - **only** contains distinct values. Creating an index **is** the answer to your performance question.

Comment: [Execution plan with only 10000 rows](https://explain.depesz.com/s/yWiC)  vs. [execution plan for 10 million rows](https://explain.depesz.com/s/HoZv)

Comment: just for informational purposes, i change the dbfiddle to have more records: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=52b808e7764bcc60ec1a99e098fea042  (which still leave me with higher `cost` values, which means I need to study that some time )